# linear spaces - simple sum - reasoning

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$X$ is linear space, we have to subspaces of $X$, $U$ and $V$ such that $U\oplus V =X$. Then
a. $X=U\cup V$
b. $U\cap V=\{0\}$
c. $\forall x\in X (x\notin U \rightarrow x \in V)$

b.  It is true, it conclusion from the fact that sum is simple.
a.  It seems to be true, but I can't see simple arguemnt. Could you help me ?
c. If a. is true then b. is true.

Comment: What are YOUR thoughts on this? Any ideas? Have you tried working out what happens in some simple cases like $X$ being $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of $U \bigoplus V= X$, b) holds, as direct summands must have trivial intersection.

a) is false, for example, take $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, and $U = <(1,0)>$ and $V= <(0,1)>$.

Thus c) is also false, as there elements which are neither in $V$ nor $U$, but are linear combinations of elements in $U$ respectively $V$.

Comment: Do you mean that $[0,1]$ is base of $U$ ? Then $U\cup V = span([0,1],[1,0])=\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Yes. I define $U$ to be the subspace spanned by the row vector $(1,0)$, but $U \cup V \neq span((1,0), (0,1)) = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I don't understand you.   Tell me, why $U\cup V\neq span([1,0], [0,1])$  $U\cup V $ ?

Comment: The definition is $U \cup V = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \quad x \in U \text{ or } x \in V\}$. So Putting in the definitions of $V$ and $ U$, we get $U \cup V = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \quad x \in span ((1,0)) \text{ or } x \in span((0,1)) \} =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \quad x = (a,0) \text{ or } x =(0,a), a \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: ok, so for c. counterexample is $[1,1]$.

Comment: Yes, that element is neither in $U$ nor in $V$.